# Make script refresh (autoclicker)

Tags: vb.net, browser, refresh

I recently created a script that constantly tries to claim xbox gamertags (xbox id's)for when they are released (Due to xbox freeing up original inactive accounts, I am trying to capture some of them automatically without having to try it everyday, and yes this is legal/fine with their ToS). I created a working script that actually claims these names over and over about 1 time every second or so. It was successful but after leaving the script running for about 30 minutes it became unresponsive. I'm not 100% sure why, but my best bet is that I need to refresh the page every so seconds. So I added a new timer called RefreshPage and what this does is it is set to refresh the page on a certain interval. So I modified my button "Turbo" (on the application) and it rapidly clicks it but it is now also set to refresh. But once I set the option to refresh in it, I got a weird error (error listed below), but here is the code for the "button" with the refresh timer in it.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Interval = 40
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Interval = 100
    Else
        Timer1.Interval = 500
    End If

    Timer1.Enabled = True
    RefreshPage.Enabled = True




    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NewGamertag").SetAttribute("value", txtTurbo.Text)

End Sub
```

And under my RefreshPage timer I have

```
  Private Sub RefreshPage_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RefreshPage.Tick
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()
 End Sub
```

Now I'm not sure why this isn't working, but if I had to take a guess looking at the error I got (http://gyazo.com/cfc3d673573d725042e3acc7142a53b9) I'd say it is probably because it is trying to autoclick the submit button while it is trying to refresh the page which obviously would cause problems. The only resolution I can think of is to only autoclick when the page is loaded and not refreshing? I don't know, if anyone could help that would be very helpful.

Edit:
Sorry if this page isn't easy to read, but I'll also include what the program looks like: http://gyazo.com/980de035b3b1f43055aeb0a50cd0b5d5 As you can see, the script logs into xbox and then goes to the change name page where I can constantly claim for new a new gamertag that are being ready to release. In the program I put the Name I want to autoclick in (RJ), but as soon as I hit Turbo, it becomes unresponsive.

Also if this helps any, here is my full source code: pastebin . com/6ZJ2z4UU

Answer (score 0):

Add a DocumentCompleted event to your WebBrowser control then.

MSDN has an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx

Comment: After looking at most of those I tried this: http://pastebin.com/Wvz0Xz9U and it seems that it would've worked, but I don't think it is still waiting for the page to load because of this error I got: http://gyazo.com/33e5ef05de6de2d4faba914b93e4ce2f I tried other ways and most of them were codes for VB.NET and not VB08.